# How can I remove <p> tag that is automatically added in react-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using react-draft-wysiwyg and it automatically adds p tags when you either start typing or click on textbox.
How can I remove these p tags?

```
const [questionState, setQuestionState] = useState<EditorState>(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

<Editor
              editorState={questionState}
              onEditorStateChange={setQuestionState}
              editorClassName='editor'
              toolbarClassName='toolbar'
              wrapperClassName='wrapper'
              ariaLabel='question'
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

that feature is from `draftjs-to-html`, not exactly from `react-draft-wysiwyg`, that does the map of unstyled to p tag

```
var blockTypesMapping = {
unstyled: 'p',
'header-one': 'h1',
'header-two': 'h2',
'header-three': 'h3',
'header-four': 'h4',
'header-five': 'h5',
'header-six': 'h6',
'unordered-list-item': 'ul',
'ordered-list-item': 'ol',
blockquote: 'blockquote',
code: 'pre'
```

};

instead of using `draftjs-to-html` you can use `draft-js-html` that has implemented a way to change that `p` tag to other you prefer.

eg:

```
convertDraftToHtml(
  rawContent, 
  undefined, 
  type => {
          if(type == "unstyled") return {element: "span"};
      }
);
```